# XML reader error - XMLStreamException in jax-ws + SSL

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, jax-ws, wss4j

Hello fellow programmers!

I have to admit I'm still new to webservices and don't know exactly how to secure them.

I try to make a call to a webservice secured by ws-security by using jax-ws and wss4j.
Everything works great while using http. But when I try to url to use https, I get following error:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: XML reader error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
```

What could I have done wrong? What could be causing this?

Thanks in advance! Any help or suggestion will be appreciated :3

Comment: "ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1] Message: Premature end of file" I guess, the file that you are trying to read is empty.

Comment: Problem is, that file exist, both when I try it out in browser, or when I use http instead of https. I tested webservice using SoapUI at the same endpoint and it shows no problems at all..